# Oracle ORDS Data Service PL/SQL Procedure cannot return more than 32767 Characters to CLOB Out parameter called from Python or Postman

Tags: python, oracle, rest, oracle-rest-data-services

1. ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
2. ```
    p_module_name    => 'EMRPRJWSTV1.0',
   ```
3. ```
    p_pattern        => 'getPriceConfigDetails',
   ```
4. ```
    p_method         => 'GET',
   ```
5. ```
    p_source_type    => 'plsql/block',
   ```
6. ```
    p_mimes_allowed  => NULL,
   ```
7. ```
    p_comments       => NULL,
   ```
8. ```
    p_source         =>
   ```

9.'DECLARE
10.    o_json_clob                CLOB;
11.    v_appname                  VARCHAR2(1000);
15.BEGIN
16.    apps.XXOM_PRJWS_API_PKG.get_price_config_details(i_json_clob => :body_text, o_json_clob => o_json_clob);

19. CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY APPS.xxom_prjws_api_pkg
    20.is
20. PROCEDURE get_price_config_details(i_json_clob       CLOB,
21. ```
                                      o_json_clob   OUT CLOB)
    ```
22. is
    24.dbms_lob.append(o_json_clob,to_clob('"item_type_code":"'|| l_line_rec_tbl(j).item_type_code||'",'));
    25.dbms_lob.append(o_json_clob,to_clob('"line_number":"'|| l_line_rec_tbl(j).line_number||'",'));

I am calling above procedure from Python/Postman to get the value of o_json_clob, when the size is less than or equal to around 32767 then it is working fine but when size of o_json_clob is going more than 32767 then PL/SQL Procedure throws an error.

However same procedure works fine when called from Oracle SQL Developer. So how do I get value of this clob variable if the size is more than 32767 characters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: o_json_clob   OUT CLOB is the out parameter of PL/SQL Procedure and I am updating this value with   dbms_lob.append(o_json_clob,to_clob('"item_type_code":"'|| l_line_rec_tbl(j).item_type_code||'",')); statement. If the length of o_json_clob is > 32767 then program is aborting when called from Python or Postman however it works when run from SQL Developer.